# download recently modified files

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, download

the code bellow do this : 
  execute a struts action whitch modify a file in the server , then download the file 
  the file is downloaded but not the last version of this file

```
$("#generateButton").live("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../generateBlame.do",
        data: { fileName: "blame", nbrParam: "2",param1 :"aaa",param2:"bbb" }
    });

    $.fileDownload('http://localhost:8080/gestionRH/fiches/decision de blame.doc');
});
```

any way to get the updated file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably the problem is due that the server take some time to refresh its resources ; so to get around this problem i forced that the downloed event is triggered after some time 
this is the code

```
function timeout_trigger() {
  $.fileDownload('path_to_file');   
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#generateButton').button({ disabled: false });
}


 $("#generateButton").live("click",function(){
 $('#generateButton').button({ disabled: true });
    $('#loading').show();
    $.post(
       '../generateBlame.do',
       { fileName: "blame", nbrParam: "2",param1 :"pop",param2:"lll" },
      function(data) {
      setTimeout('timeout_trigger()',5000);             
});
});
```

that's work , but i prefer to do it in more smart way 
any suggestions ?
there is a any methode to refresh th server ?

Answer (score 3):

Start the download action after the update has completed (on `success` callback of the ajax request)

```
$("#generateButton").live("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
       type    : "POST",
       url     : "../generateBlame.do",
       data    : { fileName: "blame", nbrParam: "2",param1 :"aaa",param2:"bbb" },
       success : function() {
           $.fileDownload('http://localhost:8080/.../decision de blame.doc');
       }

    });

});
```

Comment: i did this but the problem is remaining, it's just when i refrech my project that i get the last modified file

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `generateBlame.do` request is what is creating the file at the specified path, you need to put the `$.fileDownload` method call in the `success` handler of the request - as the request is made asynchronously.

Try this:

```
$("#generateButton").live("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../generateBlame.do",
        data: { fileName: "blame", nbrParam: "2",param1 :"aaa",param2:"bbb" },
        success: function() {
            $.fileDownload('http://localhost:8080/gestionRH/fiches/decision de blame.doc');
        },
        error(xhr, status, error) {
            alert("File generation failed - " + error);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i did this but the problem is remaining, it's just when i refrech my project that i get the last modified file